# How to remove the last 3 words from a string in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, plsql, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I have strings like these:

```
Jack & Bauer Limited Company Bristol

Streetfood Limited Company München

Brouse with High Jack UnlimiteD Company London
```

What I want to have is just the company names like:

```
Jack & Bauer

Streetfood

Brouse with High Jack
```

So in every case, I have to delete the last 3 words, because the names can be consist a lot of words.
I know I have to use regexp, but I dont know how.

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE('Brouse with High Jack UnlimiteD Company London', '\w+(\s+\w+){2}$', '')`

Comment: You have two good answers below that work for you *if* every single row in your dataset has three extra words at the end.  Is that really the case?  Or do some rows have fewer 'extra' words?

Comment: The proposed answers don't use PL/SQL though. Is that a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select regexp_replace(str, '( [^ ]+){3}$', '')
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/QXQ94165) is a rextester.

Answer (score 2):

While you ***can*** use regular expressions to do this you don't have to. This task can be accomplished using a combination of INSTR and SUBSTR:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FIELD1, 1, INSTR(FIELD1, ' ', -1, 3)-1) AS NAME
  FROM TABLE1
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00278a/7)

Best of luck.